# Resharper 5.0 Performance Issue when working on Remote Desktop?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I am a big fan of ReSharper since many years but now that I moved to a new job that we have to work into a HyperV machine via RemoteDesktop, suddenly my Visual Studio 2010 is very slow. I have a lot of lag (2 to 10 seconds) about 10 times per hours.

I decided to uninstall ReSharper and since I have no performance issue. I have search on Internet for a solution and the only suggestion I found was to not activate the option of compiling in the background. Unfortunately, this was already disactivate.

What are my solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently developing on a WS2008 VM that is running on Hyper-V. I am using VS2010/TFS2010 and Resharper 5.1.1753.4

I only have 2GB RAM on the VM and while it is a bit slow I have never experienced the lag you talk about. The only lag I get is caused by TFS.

Are you using the latest build of Resharper 5.0?

Comment: I also have downloaded Resharper 6 with the lastest build and it does the same thing. I also try JustCode from Telerik and once it's installed, few minutes after it's slow. I tested it for about 2 hours with some lag (less than Resharper but still laggy)

Comment: How much RAM do you have on your VM ?

Comment: I have 4 gigs for me. The machine itself has 32 gigs

Answer (score 1):

I have used resharper over a remote desktop connection with more than 400ms of lag time on the connection and not seen the problem you are talking about.  There has to be some issue with your network connection and the interaction with resharper, because that's not normal in my experience.

Comment: I'll contact the IT departement. What it's weird is that I have no lag what so ever when I uninstall it :\ Do you have a big solution?

Comment: @Daok - well, it's not a small solution, but i wouldn't call it big either.. I don't know why solution size would matter.  The issue with remote desktop usage is how much data graphical redraws happen.